# Building Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile with fastlane failing on iOS

Tags: ios, kotlin, jenkins-pipeline, fastlane, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I'm having an issue why trying to build a KMM project using a Jenkins pipeline and fastlane for the iOS part.

Kotlin version: 1.5.31
XCode version: 13.1
Fastlane version: 2.198.1
Ruby version: 2.6.3p62

When executing these steps locally it breaks as well. The Error that fastlane throws is `import shared: no such module 'shared'`

I figured out that if you run `pod install && fastlane xcode_build` the build brakes, but if you repeat it a second time it succeeds and creates the project.app file in the DerivedData folder of XCode.

The Jenkinsfile is working correctly on another iOS project which is not a KMM one.

Here is the Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '5', artifactNumToKeepStr: '5'))
    }
    environment{
        FIREBASE_APP = 'some-app'
        FIREBASE_TOKEN = 'some-token'
        YOUR_CRED = credentials('KeychainPassword')
        PROJECT_NAME = 'project'
    }
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Build and Deploy") {
            parallel {
                stage("iOS") {
                    agent { label 'ios' }
                    stages {
                        stage('Unlock Keychain') {
                            steps {
                                sh 'security unlock-keychain -p ${YOUR_CRED} /Users/chocho/Library/Keychains/login.keychain'
                            }
                        }
                        stage("Build") {
                            steps {
                                dir("${PROJECT_NAME}-ios"){
                                    sh "pod install"
                                    sh "fastlane xcode_build"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        stage("Archive") {
                            steps {
                                sh "cp -r ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/${PROJECT_NAME}-ios*/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}-ios.app ./"
                                sh "zip -r simulator.zip ./${PROJECT_NAME}-ios.app"
                                archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'simulator.zip', fingerprint: true
                            }
                        }
                        stage('Clean'){
                            steps{
                                sh "rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/${PROJECT_NAME}*"
                            }
                        }
                        stage("Upload") {
                            // when { branch 'develop' }
                            steps {
                                dir("${PROJECT_NAME}-ios/fastlane"){
                                    sh "fastlane test_flight_develop build_number:${BUILD_NUMBER}"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    post {
                        always {
                            sh "rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/${PROJECT_NAME}-ios*"
                            cleanWs()
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage("Android") {
                    agent { label 'ios' }
                    stages {
                        stage("Clean") {
                            when { branch 'develop' }
                            steps {
                                sh './gradlew clean'
                            }
                        }
                        stage("Build") {
                            when { branch 'develop' }
                            steps {
                                sh "./gradlew assembleRelease -Pandroid.injected.version.code=${BUILD_NUMBER}"
                            }
                        }
                        stage("Archive") {
                            when { branch 'develop' }
                            steps {
                                sh "cp ${PROJECT_NAME}-android/build/outputs/apk/release/${PROJECT_NAME}-android*.apk ./${PROJECT_NAME}-android.apk"
                                archiveArtifacts "${PROJECT_NAME}-android.apk"
                            }
                        }
                        stage("Upload") {
                            when { branch 'develop' }
                            steps {
                                sh "firebase appdistribution:distribute \
                                    ${PROJECT_NAME}-android.apk \
                                    --token ${FIREBASE_TOKEN} \
                                    --app ${FIREBASE_APP} \
                                    --groups 'group'"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    post {
                        always {
                            cleanWs()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the Fastfile that I use for fastlane

```
default_platform :ios
platform :ios do
  lane :xcode_build do
    xcodebuild(
      scheme: schemeAndTarget,
      workspace: schemeAndTarget + '.xcworkspace',
      xcargs: "-configuration 'Debug' -sdk 'iphonesimulator15.0' -destination 'generic/platform=iOS Simulator'")
  end
end
```

And here is the Podfile

```
target 'project-ios' do
  use_frameworks!
  platform :ios, '14.5'
  pod 'shared', :path => '../shared'
  pod 'R.swift', '5.4.0'
  pod 'SwiftLint', '0.45.0'
end
```

My question is, since I'm not competent enough with KMM. Why is it doing that? How am I intended to build the project for CI/CD, if the above is not a competent way of doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

so I figured it out. If anyone has the same issue, the fix for this current problem is that you have to run a gradle task in the root directory of the project, before building the iOS part.
`./gradlew generateDummyFramework`
In my case with Jenkins I added `sh './gradlew generateDummyFramework` before the `sh 'pod install'` shell command in the Build stage. This fixed the issue in question. 
The problem was caused from Cocoapods not being able to access the framework file, hence `pod install` can't configure the framework correctly. The reason for the build to fail on the first build but not on the second is because the framework file is generated when you run a build in XCode. After that Cocoapods can configure the file correctly.

 If anyone has a different answer I'm eager to know about it!